# Using terminal on VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I just started coding and I wanted to use the terminal on VS code, but every time I hit enter, it keeps showing up my laptop name as you can see in the picture. How can I use the terminal without this?

Can someone give an advice on what to do

Comment: Displaying machine name is a fairly normal thing for a terminal to do on linux or a mac.  What happens if you type `ls` in the terminal and hit enter?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and it stopped showing my machine's name. Thank you so much!